# Bug with image picker with flutter on ImageSource.Gallery

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

### Info:

1. Package: image_picker plugin for flutter, version 0.6.3+1
2. Android build only, no IOS

### Problem:

*This is my method to pick an image:*

```
  Future<void> pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    File selected = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    print(selected?.path);
    imageFilePath = selected?.path ?? imageFilePath;
  }
```

=> When using ImageSource.gallery, when choosing a picture which is not in cache, 'selected.path' prints null. When selecting a picture which is in cache, it does retrieve it, 'selected.path' prints:

```
/data/user/0/be.etnic.parrainage_mcf/cache/image_picker2517179621202627006.jpg
```

**Anyone knows what causes this problem and how I can solve it?**

### Sidenotes:

1. I can also pick an image by making a picture directly with ImageSource.camera, this doesn't give me any problems.
2. I'm not 100% sure that the selected pictures that return null
   are not in cache, but the pictures that do return correctly from
   choosing from the ImageSource.gallery all come from that
   cache-folder
3. I don't have any permissions set in my AndroidManifest.xml
   (other than Internet permission)

Comment: I dont get the fact that bugs are reported on stackoverflow and how to questions are asked in github issues :)

Comment: I am also facing the issue after adding android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"  also, is there a solution to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41459#issuecomment-563986851, following should solve the problem:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```